# Can I use code to control the LEDs in my MacBook keyboard backlight?

Tags: mac, laptop, keyboard, backlight, configure

I would like to have my MacBook keyboard backlight LEDs light up responding to the keys I press. For example, if I press a key, it should have something like a ripple effect around it with backlights. Or is there a way in general to just change the default way it just lights up the whole keyboard?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The keyboard backlight is not programmable at all, save for overall brightness